# How to call the non-specialized version of the templated function QList::operator<<

Tags: c++, qt

**Situation**

I have a `QList<QVariant>` where each `QVariant` item should be a `QList<QVariant>` of its own.  To populate the list, I want to use [QList::operator<<](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-lt-lt), which is overloaded to take both a `const T & value` and more specialized `const QList<T> & other`.

**Problem**

When I run the following code:

```
QList<QVariant> rootList;
QList<QVariant> subList = QList<QVariant>() << 1 << 2 << 3;
rootList << subList;
```

The last line here will call the `operator<< ( const QList<T> & other )` function, as far as I'm aware because that is the more specialized function which matches the type of `subList`.  The resulting list will look like this:

```
rootList: [1, 2, 3]
```

When instead I want it to look like this:

```
rootList: [[1, 2, 3]]
```

How do I force a call to the non-specialized version of `QList::operator<<`?

**Workaround**

I realize there is a [QList::push_back](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#push_back) function that is not overloaded for `QList<T>`, and that does what I am looking for.  However, I don't want to rely on a function that was only "provided for STL compatibility."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly cast `QVariantList` to `QVariant`:

```
rootList << (QVariant)subList;
```

or

```
rootList << QVariant(sublist);
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Qt but I have a feeling that the usual functional notation would be more familiar and more explicit: `rootList << QVariant(sublist);`

Comment: @LucDanton, it's your choice. I'll add to post as alternative

Comment: Great, thanks it worked!  I'm guessing static_cast<QVariant>(subList) is the preferred form.

Comment: @AerandiR, the most explicit version here is `QVariant(sublist)`. Even `static_cast` works here through conversion constructor